# Fonts broken after Meteor update

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I just updated my Meteor instance to `0.8.1`, and now my fonts are all broken. I'm getting errors such as:

```
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type
text/html:"http://localhost:3000/client/less/Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf".
```

This is happening for all of the fonts included by my project. I have bootstrap `glyphicons` that are now showing up incorrectly, I was using [`stackicons`](http://stackicons.com/) for social media badges which are now showing up incorrectly, and all of the fonts I was including are now broken. Everything shows up  as strange unicode characters or just boring default fonts.

The thing that's especially confusing is that before the update, everything worked fine. Meteor was taking care of all of this, and I didn't have to think about it.

What happened? How do I fix this?

Comment: Not familiar with meteor per se, but I've had this error before and it had to do with my .htaccess file.

Comment: Yeah Meteor handles that sort of thing for me. I literally haven't touched an `.htaccess` file since I started using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks related to the recent change in Meteor 0.8.1 ([link](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#meteor-command-line-tool)):

> Convert relative URLs to absolute URLs when merging CSS files.

Now if your CSS specifies a relative url, it is rewritten as an absolute url relative to your CSS path in the project.

For example, a CSS file /client/styles/main.css containing:

```
body { background-image: url(../assets/bg.png); }
```

would be transformed as:

```
body { background-image: url(/client/assets/bg.png); }
```

in production. See this issues for the context:

- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/186
- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/1986
- https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-bower/issues/7